# Retrofit Field override other value?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am having a really weird case here!

I am sending params to retrofit Observable

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api")
Observable<Response> track(@Field("driverid") long driverid, @Field("latitude") double latitude, @Field("longitude") double longitude);
```

but when it sends the values, latitude take longitude value

This is the request body

```
driverid=19&latitude=101.6675401&longitude=101.6675401
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: check once what value you are passing to longitude parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do like below

```
@POST("api")
    Observable<Response> track(@Query("driverid") long driverid, @Query("latitude") double latitude, @Query("longitude") double longitude);
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of fixing this that I just found, is to send

```
Observable<Response> track(@Body RequestBody body);
```